# Many-to-Many relationship in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, m2m

I have the following 3 models:

```
class Platform(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Profile(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=110, unique=True)
    platform = models.ManyToManyField(Platform)

class Register(models.Model):
    ...
    profile = models.ManyToManyField(Profile)
    ...
```

My views.py

```
def info(request):
    ...
    registers=Register.objects.all()
    ...
    for register in registers:
        profile= register.profile....???
```

I need to know the profile or profiles from a query of the Register model

is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can obtain *all* the `Profile`s related to one or more `registers` with:

```
Profile.objects.filter(register__in=registers)
```

or you can obtain the `Profile`s of a `Register` object:

```
def info(request):
    # …
    registers=Register.objects.all()
    # …
    for register in registers:
        profiles = register.profile.all()
```

but here you will hit the database *per* `register`, which might not scale very well.

You can, like [@IainShelvington says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63733013/many-to-many-relationship-in-django/63733036?noredirect=1#comment112700906_63733036), use [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch all these related `Profile`s in memory with one extra query and do the JOIN at the Django/Python level:

```
def info(request):
    # …
    registers=Register.objects.prefetch_related('profile')
    # …
    for register in registers:
        profiles = register.profile.all()
```

Comment: `Register.objects.prefetch_related('profile_set')` would eliminate the repeated database calls

Comment: if I use ```register.profile_set.all()``` 
I get the following error: ```AttributeError: 'Register' object has no attribute 'profile_set'```

Comment: @DavidCastro: did you specify a `related_name` in the `ManyToManyField`?

Comment: No, I have ```profile= models.ManyToManyField(Profile)```

Comment: @DavidCastro: never mind, I misread it. Then it is `register.profile.all()`. You might however want to rename `profile` to `profiles` (so plural), since it is a *collection* of `Profile` objects.

Comment: Yes now, thank you!!!. Why doesn't it accept ```..._ set``` as indicated by Django?

Comment: @DavidCastro: no, the `..._set` is the relation in *reverse*. But here we use the `ManyToMany` in a *forward* manner.